# Copy Column A from Table 1 and column B from Table 2 into Table 3 columns A and B

Tags: sql, database

I have table 3, with columns A and B. I want to do an insert, where A is a column I will copy from table 1, and B is a column from table 2.

What I know works:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE3(A)
SELECT A
FROM TABLE1
```

What I want:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE3(A, B)
SELECT A
FROM TABLE1
SELECT B
FROM TABLE2
```

Comment: How are you planning on mapping the column A and B in Table3 if they are from different sources ?

Comment: @ShreyasChavan Just copying columns. I know I can do it for one column for one table, but I want to do it for a second column from a second table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want every combination of A and B?  In that case:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE3 (A, B)
SELECT TABLE1.A, TABLE2.B
FROM TABLE1, TABLE2
```

Comment: You beat me to it by a second! I figured it out and was about to post the answer, thanks!

Comment: Wont that give all permuations of values in table1 vs table 2 ?

Comment: Yes, it would.  Seems like that is what huhh hhbhb wanted.